# automating logging messages for api controllers

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following controller method in my Entity Framework Core project.

I just started learning about .NetCore logging and I love it!

However I have a feeling it might become difficult to attach logging to all of my controllers.

Currently my project has quite a few controllers for various endpoints.

I started adding logging code, and I fear that I may be making it more difficult than needs to be.

So I inject the logger, then I create a few strings like `Message`, `Controller`, and `ErrorMessage`.

I then assign values to those inside the controller method as needed.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in a more automated way instead of manually all that to every controller method.

Unfortunately I can't create a base class because my controllers need to use `ControllerBase`.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PetrolStationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly petrol_ProdContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public PetrolStationController(petrol_ProdContext context, ILogger<PetrolStationController> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _stationService = stationService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [HttpGet("GetStationNodeObject/{stationId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<StationList>> GetStationLocation(Guid stationID)
    {
        Controller = this.GetType().Name.ToString();

        var stationList = await _context.StationList.FindAsync(stationID);

        if (stationList == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "stationID does not exist";
            Message = $"Endpoint: {Controller}: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()} => {ErrorMessage}";
            _logger.LogInformation(Message);
            return NotFound();
        }

        var petrolStation = await _stationService.GetStationLocation(stationID);
        Message = $"Endpoint: {Controller}: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()}, Success!";
        _logger.LogInformation(Message);

        return petrolStation;
    }
}
```

I was hoping someone could provide some insight for a better way of doing this.

thank you all

Comment: hmm so yeah, it was a `Guid`:)

Comment: yeah kinda , In this work project, it was a GUID so when I was typing out the code for my dumb game, from memory this was fresh in my mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tutorial: https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/

I am using this approach quit often. This will log all exceptions automatically and if you want more you can easily add it inside your controller. Biggest PRO is that you set up everything at one place and you get uniform log format. You can use log server or file to save logs.

Comment: That looks good but I still see they are writing messages in the controller and they show an example for `HomeController`.  So I'd still be having to add logging code like that to all of my controllers.

Comment: If you want some additional information to be logged, yes you will need to add some code to controllers, but if you need errors and warnings those will be captured and logged automatically. I am using this on multiple projects and never had to write a single line of code inside controllers.